# How can I get the last date from a list of dates in the database then compare it with the current date?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I’m trying to retrieve dates from the database then use it to compare with current date.  How can I get the last date from a list of dates in the database then compare it with the current date? Here’s what I’ve tried but I get a exception: “LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Last…”

```
  var manageDate= from d in db.Enrollments.Select(da=>da.Date) select d;
        var manageAssgnDate = from asgn in db.Enrollments.Select(asgn => asgn.Date) select asgn;
        List<DateTime> newDate = manageDate.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use lambdas:

```
// This gets the max date in the table
var manageDate = db.Enrollments.Max(da => da.Date);
```

Is this what you were asking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a work-around:

var stdAssgn= from sa in db.Assignments where sa.StudentId==currentId select sa.Date;
                   var dt = stdAssgn.ToList().Last ();
                   String a = dt.ToString();
and to convert to DateTime if needed...
                  DateTime b=Convert.ToDateTime(a);